# SQLite query not returning all result rows

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to pull out a section of rows from a SQLite 3 database using the following code:

```
function getunsolved($user) {
    $sql = "SELECT challenge FROM completed WHERE status = 0 AND username = '$user';";
    $rez = $this->query($sql);
    $temp = $rez->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM);
    return $temp;
}
```

Unfortunately, the code is only returning 1 row, and should be returning 9 rows.

Running the above SQL code on the database, and substituting a valid username for `$user` returns the correct amount of rows, so I know the problem isn't the SQL code.

My table format is as follows:
`username (TEXT), challenges (TEXT), status (INTEGER)` (in that order, if it matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php):

> SQLite3Result::fetchArray - Fetches a result row as an associative or numerically indexed array or both. By default, fetches as both.

So if you want to get all of the results, you should iterate over them and return the aggregated data:

```
$ret = array();
while($row = $rez->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM)) {
    $ret[] = $row;
}
return $ret;
```